# How to search character vector for string and where TRUE replace entire element with part of original element?

Tags: r, grepl

I am trying to write a function that takes an vector, searches for elements within that vector that contain a particular string, and replaces the entire text of that element with the first word in the original element.

for example, i have:

```
vec <- c("eolimna pala", "achnanthes lata", "navicula spp.", "diploneis spp. 2")
```

and i would like to get:

```
vec <- c("eolimna pala", "achnanthes lata", "navicula", "diploneis")
```

this is more or less what i have. any help is much appreciated. 
EDIT: it would be even more helpful if i could provide as an argument a character vector of several strings to check each element for.

```
rollToGenus <- function (vec) { 

  greps <- grepl(" spp. ", as.character(vec))

  for (i in 1:length(vec)) {
    if (greps[i] == TRUE) {
      paste(str_split_fixed(i, " ", n=6)[1])
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are `a` and `b` included in the output? they don't have spp.

Comment: i want the output to be the original vector but with replacements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't it simply the following:

```
gsub(" spp\\..*$", "", vec)
# [1] "eolimna pala"    "achnanthes lata" "navicula"        "diploneis"
```

EDIT:
`gsub` replaces (regular expression) patterns in strings. `" spp\\..*$"` looks for all `" spp."` (`\\.` escapes the `.` which means *any char*) followed by any char `.` zero/multiple times `*` til the end of the string `$`.

Your solution does nearly the same (but uses `ifelse` and `grepl` for things that `[g]sub` can do alone). That's why my solution looks cleaner and should be faster:

```
library("microbenchmark")
vec <- c("eolimna pala", "achnanthes lata", "navicula spp.", "diploneis spp. 2")
all.equal(gsub(" spp\\..*$", "", vec), 
          ifelse(grepl(" spp.", vec, fixed = TRUE), sub(" .*", "", vec), vec))
# [1] TRUE

microbenchmark(gsub=gsub(" spp\\..*$", "", vec), 
               ifelse=ifelse(grepl(" spp.", vec, fixed = TRUE), sub(" .*", "", vec), vec))
# Unit: microseconds
#    expr    min      lq     mean median     uq     max neval
#    gsub 23.301 24.1305 26.39183 25.599 26.168  56.770   100
#  ifelse 49.791 51.1235 56.00751 51.760 52.576 170.134   100
```

Comment: i'm pretty bad with string stuff. could you explain this a little bit more and why it would be better than the answer i posted just below?

Comment: @bishopia please see my edit

Answer (score 0):

Someone posted this then deleted it. it worked for me.

```
ifelse(grepl(" spp.", vec, fixed = TRUE), sub(" .*", "", vec), vec)
```